# Getting contact name from number in Android 2.3.4

Tags: android

i try to get the name of contact using number in 2.3.4 android, but it was not working.. here i have attached my code. Kindly assist.. i have tried so many ways as posted in Stack over flow, in emulator its working but fails while runs in phone..

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME, 
                                     Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };

// encode the phone number and build the filter URI
Toast.makeText(context, "sender: "+sender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL,
                                      Uri.encode(sender));

// query time
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null,
                                              null, null);

// if the query returns 1 or more results
// return the first result
if(c.getCount()>0){
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }                
}else{
    name="UnKnown";
}
```

Comment: can you post your full code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the API for [`Contacts.Phones.NUMBER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.PhonesColumns.html#NUMBER):

> public static final String **NUMBER**
>
> The phone number as the user entered it.

So the number you use in the program must be specified *exactly the same* (character by character) as the one in the phone book. This might be why it fails on the phone as your phone book might contain country code information like `+46xxxxxxxx`.

To get around this issue use [`PhoneLookup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) from [`ContactsContract`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) it will use an algorithm to check if the numbers are equal (also, 
the constants from `Contacts.Phones` are deprecated):

```
public static String getContactName(String num, ContentResolver cr) {

    Uri u = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI Uri.encode(num));
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Cursor c = cr.query(u, projection, null, null, null);

    try {
        if (!c.moveToFirst())
            return number;

        int index = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        return c.getString(index);

    } finally {
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
    }
}
```

*(This code returns the number if no contact is found with that number.)*

Comment: how pass or get ``ContentResolver cr`` from adapter??

Answer (score 0):

You can better use cursorloaders so the main thread can't be blocked. It is otiose to get the index and then get the string.

```
    private String getContactName(String num) {

    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(num));
    String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, projection, null, null,null);

    Cursor c = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    try {
        if (!c.moveToFirst())
            return num;

        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error looking up the contactname." + e);
        return num;
    }
    finally {
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
    }
}
```