# how to store value from cursor into string in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-cursor

I'm creating application that can retrieve contact name from number. While Googling, I got this block of code from this post:
[Getting contact name from number in Android 2.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785146/getting-contact-name-from-number-in-android-2-3-4)

```js
public static String getContactName(String num, ContentResolver cr) {

    Uri u = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI Uri.encode(num));
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Cursor c = cr.query(u, projection, null, null, null);

    try {
        if (!c.moveToFirst())
            return number;

        int index = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        return c.getString(index);

    } finally {
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
    }
}
```

I'm successfully able to send Number as **String num** in the function, 
but do not know how to store contact name into String. I'm not familiar with **Cursor** in Android

If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: you are already doing it by returning a string. so now what you want to do? your question is very unclear.